# find number of items waiting to be printed in printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I need to find the number of documents waiting to be printed in a printer. I have 4 printers and I need to find for particular printer based on the name. If I use

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob
```

I am getting number of items in print queue of all printers. I need to do this in C#. Is it possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob WHERE Name = 'name of printer'

Comment: Thanks, I found another way to do it but not as straightforward as yours. I haven't tried your's so cannot tell if it works but I used this http://sandeep-aparajit.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-get-printer-submitted-jobs-in-c.html

Comment: @user281693: The difference between the two methods is where the filtering takes place - this does it at the root, requesting only results for the printer we specify; the linked one just gets results for _all_ printers and then filters them out manually.